# Event To Call JavaScript Function When innerHTML has 100% completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I did a quick Google on the title and got pummelled with all this code that I didn't understand a word of.

I've been JavaScript programming for a couple of years now and am comfortable with most concepts. Except event handling. It scares me!

**The problem**

I have a div which I've wrote a script for, that scrolls the div vertically purely based on mouse position.

I get the height of the container, and height of the inner container that will "overflow".

Divide them to get a "differential" and then multiple the mouse position by this differential to get the div to scroll depending on the mouse position.

It gives me a nice clean scroll!

(If anybody wants more info on this just ask)

My problem is. The contents of this div are generated by ajax.

Therefore when the code to calculate the height of both inner and outer divs is ran, it gives the incorrect height, as they haven't been populated by data yet.

So I need to fire an function WHEN the ajax has copied the data to the innerHTML to call the `mousescroll` function.

**Extra**

Issues: I have two ajax calls that populate the scrollable div. and sometimes one gets fetched before the other and vice versa. So I need the `mousescroll` function to fire WHEN and only WHEN both of the ajax calls have completely entered all the data into the html that they can!

I was thinking about just adding a `setTimeout` but... I don't like forcing my scripts to wait!

Comment: Are you using any framework/library/utility function for your ajax calls?

Comment: even i am trying to work on same, i m using .net 4.0. good question, solution would be interesting:)

Comment: at first i didnt want to depend on jquery, but after realising i cant be bothered to fix cross browser dependancies *cough* IE *cough* i decided to go with jquery-1.7.1

Comment: You should change the title of your post because you aren't talking about custom Javascript events (that means something quite specific). I'd edit it myself but I'm not totally sure what it should be :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% clear on where the problem is. You write: "I need to fire an function WHEN the ajax has copied the data to the innerHTML to call the mousescroll function." -- do you need help with that part of it? If you're using jQuery, then you just call the mousescroll function inside of the `success` callback function of `$.ajax`.

As you point out, however, this is complicated by the other issue you bring up: there are actually two Ajax calls and you want them *both* to complete before calling the mousescroll function. To solve this, simply create a variable that is equal to zero, and then increment it within both `success` callbacks. Those callbacks would also check the value of the variable, and if it equals 1 (meaning that an Ajax call has already completed), call the mousescroll function.

pseudo code:

```
var numOfAjaxCalls = 0;

$.ajax({
    ...
    success: function(){
        if(numOfAjaxCalls = 1){
            mousescroll();
        }else{
            numOfAjaxCalls++;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. basically I need to run a function when the ajax has fetched the data. However. My ajax function fetches alot of json data, parses it, then using the .innerHTML method, I insert the parsed data into a container, now this happens twice. I thought about firing the function on the "success" command but... does the success event fire when the ajax has been recieved, OR when the innerHTML function has completed? Because i really need to ensure that the containers are FULL before firing. and the "success" appears to be called only when the request has been successful! Thanks

Comment: @AlexMorley-Finch: I think innerHTML is synchronous so there wouldn't be a way to be in a state where "innerHTML has not completed"

Comment: @AlexMorley-Finch - The success handler fires when the ajax call completes (and is successful). So it's within the success handler that you would parse the JSON and inject the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your descripion, you need to handle the ajax in the jQuery success event, then handle the actual "complete" event in your code once the two ajax events have completed and are handled properly per your requirement.